# How to check if there is a Chrome instance already open with a specific port in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

I have the following code

```
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Sources.SOURCE_PATH + "chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.setExperimentalOption("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9222");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            ex = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I would like to check if there is already an instance of Chrome open with the port 9222 before executing. Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

Make an HTTP request to the url below

```py
import requests
res = requests.get('http://localhost:9222/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer')
```

If selenium is not running on this port 9222 then by hitting above URL it will give you 
`Unable to connect`

If selenium server is already running on port 9222 then it will shut down the server and will give you
`OKOK`.

You can then use these to handle execution as you desire.